# The curve $(\cos(\sin x),\sin(\cos x))$ as plotted by Wolfram Alpha

Tags: trigonometry, wolfram-alpha, curves

I've just gotten this from Wolfram Alpha:

[image]

It makes no sense to me. $\cos(\sin x)$ is never zero so how can this curve cross the $y$-axis?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't cross the y axis. Look closely at the tick marks on the x-axis, and you will see that the axes in the picture do not meet at the origin.

Comment: Ahh... I did notice that the marks seemed off, but I had no idea how to interpret that! Now I understand that the vertical line is simply not the y axis. Thank you.